# In strapi what are api templates for?

Tags: strapi

I've started playing with strapi to see what it can do.

When generating an api through strapi studio, it generates a set of base files to handle the model and api calls.

In the entity folder (e.g. article), there's a templates/default folder created with a default template. For an article entity, I get a `ArticleDefault.template.json` file with this:

```
{
  "default": {
    "attributes": {
      "title": {},
      "content": {}
    },
    "displayedAttribute": "title"
  }
}
```

In strapi studio I also then add additional templates for each entity, given it multiple templates.

The command line api generator does not create the templates folder.

I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation I read.

What are the generated templates for?
When would I use them, and how would I choose a particular template if I have multiple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm one of the authors of Strapi.

A template is like a schema of data. Let’s take a simple example. You have an API called `Post`, sometimes your post have a title and a content attribute, but other times, your post have a title, a subtitle, a cover and a content attribute. In both cases, we’re talking about the same API `Post` but your schema of data is different. That’s why we implemented the templates! Your needs could be different for the same content.

Then, as you said the CLI doesn't generate a template folder in project. The Studio doesn't use the same generator as the CLI but the behavior of your API is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the details on this. How does one use one particular template or another during an api call?

Comment: You just have to add a template attribute in your request. For example `http://localhost:1337/article?template=default`.